# Extra operand 'ago' when trying to parameterize bash date

Tags: bash

I'm following [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382099/bash-date-d-throws-invalid-date-when-date-is-parameterized) to parameterize date. But this code:

```
FROM_DATE=$(date --date='1 day ago' +"%F")

OPTARG="1 day ago"
echo $OPTARG
FROM_DATE=$(date --date=${OPTARG} +"%F")
echo $FROM_DATE
```

gives me an error:

```
date: extra operand ‘ago'’
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Oh duh, I missed the quoting problem.  This is a FAQ.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 3):

Quote the expansion of `$OPTARG`. Without quotes, `--date=1 day ago` is split into three arguments: `--date=1`, `day`, and `ago`.

```
FROM_DATE=$(date --date="$OPTARG" +"%F")
```